# HTML: Unexplained vertical gap between text-wrapped inline-block elements with an image?

Tags: html, image, css

Why is there a gap here (ie 'element3' LOWER than 'element4')?

```
       +----------------+           +----------------+ 
       |+------++------+|     VS.   |+------++------+|
       ||  1   ||  2   ||           ||  1   ||  2   ||
       ||      ||      ||           ||      ||      ||
gap    |+------++------+|           |+------++------+|
 ----> |        +------+|     ----> |+------++------+|
why??  |+------+|+--+ 4||    no gap ||      ||++   4|| 
       ||  3   |||Im|  ||           ||  3   ||++    ||
       ||      ||+--+  ||           ||      ||      ||
       ||      |+------+|           |+------++------+|
       |+------+        |           |                |
       +----------------+           +----------------+
```

Here is the code

```
<?php
echo "
    <style type=text/css>
    a.keys{
       display:inline-block;
       width:100px;height:100px;
       border:1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    <div class=panel style='width:250px;height:100%;border:1px solid #000;'>
    <a  class=keys  href='#'>1</a>
    <a  class=keys  href='#'>2</a>
    <a  class=keys  href='#'>3</a>
    <a  class=keys >
        <img src=img/apple.jpg  style='width:50px;height:50px;' >
    </a>
    </div>
";
?>
```

I.e. why is the text-wrapped element 3 LOWER positioned than element 4?
It has something to do with the image (and size), but I can't figure out why an image SMALLER than the parent element would cause such behaviour?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Not sure why byt if you put some text in #4 it fixes itself. Perhaps use a `&nbsp;` or `<br/>`?

Comment: It works using `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block;`; however, it's a bit different visually.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use `display: inline-block` block here? You can achieve the same thing using floated elements quite easily.

Comment: @Elbert: that is, text *instead* of the image.

Comment: @JCOC611 A `<br/>` right after the image works as well.

Comment: I was messing around with `&nbsp;` and `<br />` and `img { display: block }` and `img { vertical-align: bottom }`, but I couldn't get a solution which looked the same quickly testing in IE/Firefox/Opera.

Comment: @Elbert: It didn't work for me in Chrome using thirtydot's fiddle, placing `<br>` right after the image.

Comment: @thirtydot: that link is useful; and BTW the gap VARIES if the picture size is changed! (e.g. height:10px produces a much smaller gap??!! - What really annoys me is the fact that I don't understand it why it happens...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `vertical-align:top` specified on `.keys`.

Comment: Thanks, at least that's working now OK (although I was under the impression that `vertical-align` was/should be reserved for `<td>`?!). And do you happen to know, why the gap existed in the first place?

Comment: It probably exists because the height of the fourth anchor is moreso than the 3rd and since they are in the same row the 4th drags the 3rd down because the default valign is baseline, not top.

Comment: but why IS the height of the 4th anchor greater? they're **both 100px** high, and shouldn't really be affected by a **50px high** image inside?! - I know it must be something to do with the baseline, but still it puzzles me...

Answer (score 1):

"**vertical-align:top**" on just the image works:

```
<div class=panel style='width:250px;height:100%;border:1px solid #000;'>
   <a class=keys href='#'>1</a>
   <a class=keys href='#'>2</a>
   <a class=keys href='#'>3</a>
   <a class=keys >
      <img src=img/apple.jpg style='width:50px;height:50px;**vertical-align:top**' >
   </a>
</div>
```

See - http://jsbin.com/opejo4/2

changing "**height:100px**" to "**line-height:100px**" in a.keys also does the trick.

```
<style type=text/css>
   a.keys{
      display:inline-block;
      width:100px;
      line-height:100px;
      border:1px solid #000;
   }
</style>
<div class=panel style='width:250px;height:100%;border:1px solid #000;'>
   <a class=keys href='#'>1</a>
   <a class=keys href='#'>2</a>
   <a class=keys href='#'>3</a>
   <a class=keys >
       <img src=img/apple.jpg style='width:50px;height:50px;' >
   </a>
</div>
```

See - http://jsbin.com/opejo4/4

Comment: that is interesting! and does seem to fix it as well (without actually changing the position of the image within the container!)

Comment: You can also get this to work by specifying line-height:100px on a.keys. http://jsbin.com/opejo4/3

Comment: "height" is the height of the container (i.e. the size of box3). "line-height" is the vertical distance between the top of the first box and the top of the next box (vertically).

Comment: would you do this **routinely** (specifying `line-height`)? Might be necessary, since this behaviour came as a real surprise to me, and I may not even have spotted it if the enclosed image had been 10px in size...

Comment: @ajo, no, not routinely. I'm curious what math is used by the browser to ascertain its computed line-height for the positioning of box3. We should look it up in the spec to see if it makes sense or if it is deviant browser behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though it could be your html mark up.

Try editing the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="panel" style="width:250px;height:100%;border:1px solid #000;">
  <a class="keys" href="#">1</a>
  <a class="keys" href="#">2</a>
  <a class="keys" href="#">3</a>
  <a class="keys" href="#">
    <img src="img/apple.jpg" style="width:50px;height:50px;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Also, assign `vertical-align:top` to your css as suggested by [meder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145190/meder):

```
a.keys{
       display: inline-block;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       vertical-align: top;
}
```